# How to MDC web with a backend? (node.js backend file)

Tags: node.js, mdc-components

MDC web components use Webpack for rendering the website.
I want to use a proper node.js backend while using MDC in the HTML (.ejs) files that it serves. How am I supposed to use MDC and a node.js backend together in a project?

MDC web docs don't have any information related to connection to a backend (even a node backend).
MDC web uses `npm start` to start the server, while we need to use `node app` to start the server itself. Isn't there any way we can make MDC run with `node app` along with the backend?

P.S: I'm using express.js, mognoose, mocha, body-parser and ejs

Comment: Just run them in different ports?

Comment: That annoyed me more than it should have. Is there no other solution?